# Passing a list as a parameter in Jquery or Duplicate Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm doing a school project for children in a kindergarten.
Must drag a img to a specific gap which I am calculating its position with offset * *, because this hole is part of the background image, I know, impractical, but that I was given the project.

But the functions in Jquery not I want to run this type of parameters:

```
  Var fruits = ['.el1', '.el2', '.el3', '.el4']
```

Only I are taking the first element of the list as a parameter of functions.
This is my code:
HTML:

```
 <div class="element" style="list-style:none">
                        <li><img src="img-d/cascara de banana-01.png" class="banana2 el1"     id=""  alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img-d/cascara de huevo-01.png" class="huevo2 el2"         id="" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img-d/hojas secas-01.png" class="hojas2 el3"                  id="" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img-d/manzana-01.png" class="manzana2 el4"                        id=""   alt=""></li>
                    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
var fruits = ['.el1', '.el2', '.el3', '.el4'];
$(document).on('ready', function(){
                $(fruits[0],fruits[1],fruits[2],fruits[03]).click(function() {

                    var top_left1 = $( fruits[0]).offset();
                    var top_left2 = $( fruits[1]).offset();
                    var top_left3 = $( fruits[2]).offset();
                    var top_left4 = $( fruits[3]).offset();

                    if (top_left1.top >=230 && top_left1.top <=330 && (top_left.left1 >=620 && top_left.left1 <=700)) {
                        console.log('Bravo!')
                        }
                });

                $(fruits[0],fruits[1],fruits[2],fruits[03]).draggable();



        });
```

But write this `$(fruits[0]).draggable();` , `$(fruits[0]).click(function()` and  `$(fruits[0]).draggable();` the first image you can drag
but I need drag all the images  and evaluates its offset, to know the position of each.

Answer (score 1):

`$(fruits[0],fruits[1],fruits[2],fruits[03])` is creating numerous arguments when you only want one that is a string

Try

```
$(fruits.join()).click...// OR .draggable
```

Another more efficient way is:

```
var $fruits = $('.el1, '.el2, '.el3, .el4').click(function() {

  var top_left1 = $fruits.eq(0).offset();
  var top_left2 = $fruits.eq(1).offset();
  var top_left3 = $fruits.eq(2).offset();
  var top_left4 = $fruits.eq(3).offset();

  if (top_left1.top >= 230 && top_left1.top <= 330 && (top_left.left1 >= 620 && top_left.left1 <= 700)) {
    console.log('Bravo!')
  }
}).draggable();
```

And doing it the last way you could then use one class or `parent > child` relationship selector for all of the fruits elements